# Encrypted (Secure) Data Communication C# -> Remote MySQL with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2013

We have accomplished a data communication with a C# winforms project between a SQL Server and Remote MySQL (WEB) database (Unix platform). All the data is being updated with a custom made software.

What we want is that this communication must be encrypted (secure) when we update, insert a row or when a sql select statement is being made.

**IS there a way that Visual Studio can secure this communication line?**

All the data right now is open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL supports secure connections using SSL, and **MySQL Connector/Net** supports this.  You need `SslMode=Required;` in the connection string and you need a certificate.

Lots of details on the MySQL site:

[Tutorial: Using SSL with MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear regarding endpoints. But I guess you need at least to communicate with SQL Server using SSL from VS. You can read about that [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Alternatively you can make secured network connection itself (using VPN, IPSec).

My SQL also supports TLS as well. So you need to read documentation.

**UPDATE:** I cannot help you with Plesk (it is different topic). But I guess SQL Server when installed should use some SSL certificate. Unfortunately I think it will be untrusted... So to use that certificate and skip certificate validation you can add this to your connection string:

```
 Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;
```

But keep in mind that such connection can be impacted by Man-in-The-Middle attack. So it is better to setup server in right way.

Comment: Is there a way to arrange this with the Parallels Plesk 12? Handy for generating the SSL certifcates?

Comment: Does anyone use this kind of solutions with the Parallels Plesk 12 and the SSL with MySQL Connector/Net?

Comment: Which exactly solution do you mean?

Comment: We are using Parallels Plesk 12 for adding the MySQL databases. Is it possible to add the SSL for the MySQL Connector/Net?

Comment: I think you need create new question and ask for Plesk community and it is of course not for stackoverflow (it is of-topic here, stackoverflow is for programming-related questions). But I am sure you can ask for any environment and administration help (including Plesk) here: serverfault.com.

Comment: You are right sorry about this. My mistake :) I will ask the Plesk Question at the serverfaul.com site.